# Why ArcTan[x,y] limits yield different answers for symbolic and numeric input

Tags: functions

I can't find any reason why in version 12.1

```
Limit[ArcTan[3, x]/x, x -> 0]
(*1/3*)
```

contradicts to

```
Limit[ArcTan[y, x]/x, x -> 0]
(*Indeterminate if Re[y^2]>0&&Re[y/Sqrt[y^2]]>0*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Assumptions -> y > 0` gives the correct result (v12.2)

```
Limit[ArcTan[y, x]/x, x -> 0, Assumptions -> y > 0]
(*1/y*)
```

Comment: Thanks, with assumptions the same answer also in 12.1. Anyway, the generated conditions are misleading.

Comment: @user18792 Thanks, keep in mind the meaning of  `Indeterminate :  is a symbol that represents a numerical quantity whose magnitude cannot be determined`. That's why additional assumptions are necessary.

Comment: Or `Piecewise[{Limit[ArcTan[y, x]/x, x -> 0, Assumptions -> #], #} & /@ {y > 0, y < 0, y == 0}]`